# how to communicate two outlets

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have two router outlets in my aplication:

`app.component.html`

```
<my-component>
  <router-outlet name="header"></router-outlet>
</my-component>  

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

when navigation appears, I want to navigate in both at the same time.

when I do something like **`[routerLink]="['./mainpage']`**

I want it for all outlets, how can I do it?

Answer (score -1):

Try dynamic component instead of one of outlet

Comment: sorry, I can't see your point, could you please explain it a bit more?